# php, postman- get request with authorization token bearer doesent work

Tags: php, get, request, postman

```
authorizationResponse = {type: "authorization_response",response: {"access_token":"3VH1nr_EukBPqelzH5h5INuwaMh4rIsw","id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Im9ubGluZWludm9pY2Uy
NjE5QGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjp0cnVlLCJ1c2VyX21ldGFkYXRhIjp7ImZpcnN0X25hbWUiOiJIIiwiZ2l2ZW5OYW1lIjoiQmVhbGUiLCJsYXN0X25hbWUiOiJCZWFsZSIsIm5hbWUiOiJIIiwidXNlcl9wcmVmZXJlbmNlcyI6eyJQYXBlcmxlc3MiOiJmYW
xzZSIsIlByb21vdGlvbmFsU3RhdHVzIjoiZmFsc2UiLCJQcm9tb3Rpb25hbENvbW1UeXBlIjoiRW1haWwiLCJTZXJ2aWNlQWxlcnRzQ29tbVR5cGUiOiJFbWFpbCIsIlNlcnZpY2VBbGVydHNTdGF0dXMiOiJmYWxzZSIsIlBob25lTnVtYmVyIjoiIiwiTW9iaWxlTnVtYmVyIjoi
IiwiT0JQU3RhdHVzIjoidHJ1ZSIsIklzU2V0dGluZ1VwZGF0ZWQiOiIifSwiZGVmYXVsdF9hY2NvdW50IjoiNDA2NDQxMCJ9LCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiYXV0aDB8NWUwYmM4OGY0MjhiM2IxMDMzZTVhMzc0IiwiYXBwX21ldGFkYXRhIjp7ImZpc191c2VybmFtZSI6IjEyMzllODlhNT
ExZDRkYzQ4YjU0ZTQ2ZWE2NDBiZTk2IiwidXNlcl9yb2xlIjoiQ3VzdG9tZXIiLCJjZGhfY29udGFjdF9wcm9maWxlX2lkIjoiMzcwMTExNSIsInJlZ2lzdHJhdGlvbl9zdGF0dXMiOiJDRCIsInVzZXJfdHlwZSI6Ik9SIiwiZmlzX3N5bmNfc3RhdHVzIjoiQ0QiLCJzc29fZmxh
ZyI6Ik4iLCJjZGhfaWQiOiIzNTkzNDg1IiwibXJfb3JpZ2luYWxfaWQiOiIifSwiaWRlbnRpdGllcyI6W3sidXNlcl9pZCI6IjVlMGJjODhmNDI4YjNiMTAzM2U1YTM3NCIsInByb3ZpZGVyIjoiYXV0aDAiLCJjb25uZWN0aW9uIjoiVXNlcm5hbWUtUGFzc3dvcmQtQXV0aGVudG
ljYXRpb24iLCJpc1NvY2lhbCI6ZmFsc2V9XSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hdXRoLnJlcHVibGljc2VydmljZXMuY29tLyIsInN1YiI6ImF1dGgwfDVlMGJjODhmNDI4YjNiMTAzM2U1YTM3NCIsImF1ZCI6ImFrN2czc3pJNTV6ZVQzWWR2c2FIcktCTVN6dWYwN1JqIiwiaWF0Ijox
NTkxNjM5OTY2LCJleHAiOjE1OTE2NDIwNjZ9.O6Lr6mwdRDGnkajLvjles5OZUE6bdgeIc5NDmerKkyk","scope":"openid email user_metadata user_id app_metadata identities given_name offline_access","expires_in":86400,"refresh_token
":"wOSUKBkpPBE5cP2Fvjhqk_IyaVaUe1Yn-PMDlqvz2PiDr","token_type":"Bearer","state":"-cnRVfTo5leolNpTONy-08usnorvye89"}};v
```

From this page, I get the id_token because I need to put it in headers to get another page, but when I do it, I can't get the JSON page, instead, I receive and simple HTML page and that is not what I need. I also tried with the postman, I copied all headers and URL in postman but can't get the good response that i need. My header look like this:

```
authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.RnPasIlFFHOhn7yvs7aHKepLZqdlobM3rAJH1TzxfNU
```

but something doesn't work good, any help, how at least I can get a good response in postman?

Answer (score 0):

So, from I understood, you have troubles sending a request using the authorization header bearer token with Postman ?

If it is indeed the case, here's how to do it (just put the token in the form to the right, without the quotes of course) =>

[image: example of how to use bearer auth header]

If it's not what you asked, well I tried to help ^^